# Creating a time with a specific time and timezone in momentjs doesn't appear to work as per the doco

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to set an arbitrary date/time in momentjs with a specific timezone such that the timezone is stamped on the object with the original hh:mm values.

From the doco at http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ - this is definitely possible.

However, from further testing (see http://jsfiddle.net/patsimon/SFf5V/2/), things don't quite work as they are document too.

From the doco:

```
moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto").format(); // "2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00"
```

From my running code:

```
moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto").format(); // "2013-11-17T20:55:00-05:00"
```

This will obviously differ for others who run this from a timezone different to mine (+10:00) - but I was led to believe that the whole point of this method was to only honour the timezone explicitly provided?

Comment: There is no substitute for good documentation. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and has already been reported here:

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/57

Comment: Thanks Matt - would there be a possibility of updating the doco (or removing it until it works as written)?